# FlutterError (Cannot get size from a render object that has not been through layout

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

> FlutterError (Cannot get size from a render object that has not been through layout.
> The size of this render object has not yet been determined because this render object has not yet been through layout, which typically means that the size getter was called too early in the pipeline (e.g., during the build phase) before the framework has determined the size and position of the render objects during layout.
> The size getter was called for the following element:
> CustomPaint-[GlobalKey#c90dd]
> The render object from which the size was to be obtained was: RenderCustomPaint#70cc3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
> creator: CustomPaint-[GlobalKey#c90dd] ← Stack ← Padding ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Row ← ColoredBox ← Container ← DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#f3e51 ink renderer] ← NotificationListener ← ⋯
> parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
> constraints: MISSING
> size: MISSING
> painter: _LinearPainter#eeb01())

SignInView:

```
class SignInView extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignInView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: Image.asset('assets/logo/myliblogo.png'),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/');
              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                    const Color(0xff273043),
                  ),
                  minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                    Size(size.width, 40),
                  )),
              child: Text(
                'Google',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .bodyLarge!
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 12),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

main:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/signin', // İlk açılışta SignInView sayfasını açar
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomeView(),
        '/home': (context) => HomeView(),
        '/signin': (context) => const SignInView(),
        '/addbook': (context) => const AddBookView(),
        '/profile': (context) => const ProfileView(),
      },
      onUnknownRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: const Center(
            child: Text('Birşeyler ters gitti'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried Expanded but it is not working

Comment: couldn't reproduce, can you share the _complete_ code?

Comment: https://github.com/dogukanozgurylmz/mylib_app